# SPSS, transform data, one variable, into ten different variables

Tags: python, syntax, statistics, spss

I have data, in one variable. It is about 800 numbers. I need actually to work with the median of every 10 value. I realize that it is much more practical to use ten different variables, as these 10 values are attributes to one case/measurement in my experiment. Easier to calculate median this way. Can this be done via syntax or in combination with python? SPSS does support python.

Many many thanks for any input. I will eventually have to it number by number. Hope someone got any idea

Comment: This sounds like a simple problem but please add a clearer description of the structure of your data, or better yet add some sample data so we can propose relevant solutions

Answer (score 0):

For SPSS Modeler: You can try to create a variable that receive 1 to 80 in the same dataset and then calculate the median using the Aggregate node choosing the key variable the 1-80 variable and below the main variable and choose also the option median.

SPSS will calculate the median 80 times for you.

[SPSS Reference for Aggregate Node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/aggregate_overview.htm)